# Plausible issues of not having a center stand and solutions for those?

Tags: maintenance, tires

**Important:** This question is specific to countries like India, when there might be issues to maintain the bikes without center stand, because of lower facilities available at most of the garages

I am going to buy a bike: [hero splendor pro classic](http://www.heromotocorp.com/en-in/the-bike/splendor-pro-classic-73.html),

I like the bike, its not too costly,  and everything is just fine for a low budget bike. But there is just one thing which is killing me,

**The bike doesn't have a center stand.**

I guess it would be really problematic when there is a puncture in the tire. Would it be alright for the mechanic to remove the puncture without the center stand?

**So what could be Plausible issues of not having a center stand and solutions for those?**

(I just don't want to push my bike to many mechanics and get the same answer: you don't have a center stand , get out of here)

Comment: If this is not a dealbreaker for you, buy the bike as you can always get a stand to do your repair job.

Comment: @hagubear I mean bike has not got a center stand, and in india its even rare to find a repair stand in a garage

Comment: Okay in India then....YOU NEED A STAND...

Comment: While I feel your dilemma, what is the question here? It sounds more like a rant for the bike having a lack of a center stand. It is up to you whether or not you'll be happy with or without the center stand, therefor it comes down to opinion. I'm sorry that I'm voting to close this, but don't feel it is appropriate given how SE works. If you'd like to reshape it into a better question, I'm sure it will get better support.

Comment: @Paulster2.. I understand, my question may sound a little off-topic to people outside india, but this question if asked for an indian bike, is more about maintenance, and I have properly tagged it as well.

Comment: Maybe it's the way you are asking it then. As it stands, it's not a fit for the site. I have reread it several times and cannot discern a *specific* question in the mix.

Comment: Yep - I'd have to agree. This has nothing to do with maintenance, but everything to do with your personal preferences.

Comment: @RoryAlsop.. ok so what does that mean.. personal preferences.. what do you wish users to post here? useless scrap, or something really helpful to themselves and others..

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz ... what we are saying is, the question is written well, it's just *we cannot answer it for you because you will have to make up your own mind*. If you are looking for someone to *tell* you what to do, you've come to the wrong place. I could give you *my opinion*, but that would not be in keeping with the SE way. You want us to solve your dilemma, but we cannot do that for you ... you must do it for yourself. Either buy the bike and deal with not having a center stand, or get one which has one. Not much else to say.

Comment: @Paulster2.. So you mran SE is not about solving dilemma? Right? Well well.. Its all about that.. And its really about solving **my problem** which may be sometimes useful to future readers.. Well if u really dont agree. Go and read help center amd faq.. I would not like to teach SE rules to someone with highest rep on an SE site.. Plz

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz ... I think you misunderstand. Yes, SE is about solving problems and dilemmas. This dilemma is one you have to solve for yourself. You want us to make up your mind for you, *which we cannot do, nor should we do*. Your question boils down to, "*Should I or should I not buy this bike?*" which in essence is a shopping question.

Comment: @Paulster2.. Should i or shouldn't i, considering the ease in maintenence is, and yes , is an on topic question on this site.

Comment: @NoDownvotes  correct me if i'm wrong, are you looking for plausible issues of not having a center stand and solutions for those? In which case, just format the question to better reflect that.

Comment: @chilljeet.. yes

Comment: read the edit to my answer

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz ... I amended my vote, because now it is an on-topic question. Thank you for clarifying for us, as this makes a lot more sense on an SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fairly easy, and cheap to add a center stand to the bike once you buy it. It may even be an accessory available at the dealer

[image]

[Found here](http://www.tradeindia.com/fp706366/Center-Stand-For-Hero-Honda-Splendor.html)

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz It doesn't answer your question as you asked it, but if if were me I would have the stand for me if no one else. To much of a pain not to have one.

Answer (score 6):

Mechanics are very resourceful, and I doubt you'd have any issue working with them in India, even in ill equipped small shops. The company itself would have taken cognizance of this fact. Also, maybe this was a design decision since this is styled like a "cafe racer".
You might have to shell out a little extra for the little inconvenience you cause. Get a repair stand if you undertake any amount of maintenance work yourself. This hardly sounds like a deal breaker.
Where I see this becoming an issue is if you find yourself stranded with a flat (long solo rides?). In this case where the best option is to remove the wheel yourself and transport it to a shop, you'l have to deal with the annoyance you're foreseeing.
Also, since we're talking about India, where parking spaces are optimized like latest compression algorithms in data storage, you might miss the ability to squeeze your bike into tight parking opportunities. Kidding there.
*edit*
Installing a center stand should be a fairly easy job! I'm fairly certain that you could buy an oem center stand for the HERO SPLENDOR and have it fixed to this model as the chassis is most likely to be the same. Even if not, it shouldn't be something your mechanic can't handle.
Here -
[image: Auto Expo 2014 Delhi]
It's been done.

Comment: actually I have had an issue with not having a center stand before, I had an M80 with broken center stand, and I had to push the bike for miles, to find mechanic who would be interested in  repairing it. Also I am not worried about optimized parking spaces in india, So do you think I shoul neglect caring about the center stand ?

Comment: And also, If you can, can you advice buying this bike personally, or other within the same price range in india?